# How to ask user for camera and microphone permissions when he tries to upload file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

if we use `Flutter` `InAppWebView` to upload files, in all examples we have to ask for camera and microphone permissions in `main` function. For me it looks bad practise, because at a start time we don't know yet when and if user will really need access to file uploads.

So, it is more logical to ask for such a permission when user opens "Choose file" dialog for the very first time.

Is there any way for `InAppWebView` to intercept event when user opens file chooser for the very first time and ask permissions in such event handler?